# Trouble Turning ESRI Feature Layer On and Off with simple html button

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble trying to get an ESRI Feature Layer turned on and off with an html button.  Right now the button should just add the feature layer to the map.  The feature layer (featureLayer2) was created using ESRI's ArcMap Online.  I don't have access to ArcMap Server so using a dynamic feature layer does not seem like an option.  The feature layer is created in a function and then pushed to an array that is outside the function (myArray).  When the button is clicked myFunction() should be called.  myFunction() should add the layer to the map.  I am also having trouble getting the largest shapefile to show at a certain zoom level.  I am not sure if I need to simplify the shapes or if the layers won't show past a certain zoom due to their extent going off the page.  My biggest concern is getting the button to work but if anybody has advice about the shapefile that would be awesome too.  The code is below, the feature layers are available to the public so you should be able to run the code and see the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>FeatureLayer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>

<style>
html, body, #map {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#map{ position: relative;}
 #legendPane {
     position: absolute;
     top:1%;
     left:5%;
     right:5%;
     height:19%;
     width:90%;
     border: 3px solid silver;


      border-radius: 25px;
     background-color:grey;
     z-index: 10;
    }

</style>

<script>
myArray = [];
require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer
  ) {

    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [-91.7857, 43.3033],
      zoom: 12
    });

    /****************************************************************
     * Add feature layer - A FeatureLayer at minimum should point
     * to a URL to a feature service or point to a feature collection 
     * object.

      map.addLayer(featureLayer2);
     map.addLayer(featureLayer3);
     var featureLayer3 = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/wsMerged/FeatureServer/0");
 map.addLayer(featureLayer);
   myArray.push(featureLayer2);
 var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/WBD_HU_12_IA_Select/FeatureServer/0");
    var featureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/hydricSoilsMerged/FeatureServer/0");
     map.addLayer(featureLayer3);
   ***************************************************************/

    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/WBD_HU_12_IA_Select/FeatureServer/0");
    var featureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/hydricSoilsMerged/FeatureServer/0");

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    myArray.push(featureLayer2);




  });  

  function myFunction(){map.addLayer(myArray[0])};
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">  <div id="legendPane"><button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">Click to see hydric soils</button></div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the layer toggle function.  I had to pass the map into the array as well and then call my function outside everything else.  You should note that the button only adds a layer - it currently does not toggle.  Still having trouble figuring out why the large feature layer only displays at certain zooms.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>FeatureLayer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>

<style>
html, body, #map {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#map{ position: relative;}
 #legendPane {
     position: absolute;
     top:1%;
     left:5%;
     right:5%;
     height:19%;
     width:90%;
     border: 3px solid silver;


      border-radius: 25px;
     background-color:grey;
     z-index: 10;
    }

</style>

<script>
myArray = [];
require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer
  ) {

    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [-91.7857, 43.3033],
      zoom: 12
    });
myArray.push(map);
    /****************************************************************
     * Add feature layer - A FeatureLayer at minimum should point
     * to a URL to a feature service or point to a feature collection 
     * object.

      map.addLayer(featureLayer2);
     map.addLayer(featureLayer3);
     var featureLayer3 = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/wsMerged/FeatureServer/0");
 map.addLayer(featureLayer);
   myArray.push(featureLayer2);
 var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/WBD_HU_12_IA_Select/FeatureServer/0");
    var featureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/hydricSoilsMerged/FeatureServer/0");
     map.addLayer(featureLayer3);
   ***************************************************************/

    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/WBD_HU_12_IA_Select/FeatureServer/0");
    var featureLayer2 = new FeatureLayer("https://services6.arcgis.com/EnvQRR6Ah8vLF2fy/arcgis/rest/services/hydricSoilsMerged/FeatureServer/0");

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    myArray.push(featureLayer2);




  });  

  function myFunction(){myArray[0].addLayer(myArray[1])};
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">  <div id="legendPane"><button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">Click to see hydric soils</button></div></div>
</body>

</html>
```